# Why can't i uppercase the first letter of a textbox as the user types it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to force the user to input a capital letter into the textbox as the first character input. Not sure why this isn't working.

```
    private void txtStart_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        char[] letters = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        string key = txtStart.Text;
        foreach (char letter in letters) {
            if (key[0] == letter) {
                key = key.ToUpper();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code isn't working because you are changing the string toUpper only in the variable and not the textbox. Also doing key.ToUpper() will change the case of the entire string!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're setting the whole text to upercase *and* you're not setting the property of the textBox to the new value. It's a good idea to save the old text in a private property as well. Try this:

```
private string _oldText = "";
private void txtStart_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    if ((txtStart.SelectionStart <= txtStart.Length - _oldText.Length || txtStart.SelectionStart == 0) && char.IsLower(txtStart.Text.FirstOrDefault()))
    {
        var selectionStart = txtStart.SelectionStart;
        var selectionLength = txtStart.SelectionLength;
        txtStart.TextChanged -= txtStart_TextChanged;
        txtStart.Text = $"{Char.ToUpper(txtStart.Text.First())}{(txtStart.Text.Length > 1 ? txtStart.Text.Substring(1) : "")}";
        txtStart.Select(selectionStart, selectionLength);
        txtStart.TextChanged += txtStart_TextChanged;
    }
    _oldText = txtStart.Text;
}
```

Actually I made a slightly better checking for wether the first letter is lowercase, you might realize that I set the cursorPosition to the former position as well and I temporally removed the event handler to prevent getting stuck in event handling as an infinite loop.

Comment: the .isLower / .toLower methods can only be called on strings, not chars. Any other ideas?

Comment: @TylerArnett Actually this is not true: https://www.dotnetperls.com/char-islower and https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.char.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there is an issue with the final 2 lines in the method.

Comment: Even if it wasn't possible to do a `Char.ToUpper` you could make a string of size one from the input's first character, apply the `ToUpper` method to that string and then proceed to do the concatenation of it with the rest and apply it by doing the assignment `txtStart.Text = bla-bla-bla;`

Comment: You can't change string characters like that. The array values are read only.

Comment: You should probably do it in a complier...`isLower` should be `IsLower`, the cursor moves to the beginning of the textbox whenever someone types a letter, so they all end up capital, and if you backspace so that there are no letters, you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Of course you could remember the cursorPosition and reposition the cursor again, but then the cursor would flicker everytime the user types. This obviously isn't the right way to do it (you should only execute this test if the cursorPosition is at the length of the entered text), but it answers the question

Comment: I think I thought of everything that could happen now. Kindly draw my attention on other possible mistakes I made.

Comment: You have to initiailize `_oldText` or you'll get a null reference exception on the first keypress, when you try to access `_oldText.Length`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private void txtStart_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    string str = txtStart.Text;

    if (str == "")
        return;

    if (str.Length > 1)
        str = char.ToUpper(str[0]) + str.Substring(1);
    else
        str = str.ToUpper();

    txtStart.Text = str;
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that the cursor moves to the beginning of the textbox, so all letters end up capital and in reverse order. Remember, setting the `.Text` property inside this method is going to call this method again (the text is changing)

Comment: I did wonder if the event would fire again but I couldn't test it. It might be better to use the KeyDown event and check if it's the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

One somewhat reliable way to do this is to have a class-level variable that keep track of whether or not your code is changing the text, or if the user is changing the text. That way, when your code resets the text, you basically ignore the `TextChanged` code.

I also set a class variable to the last selection start position in the text box. This handles the case where the user pastes text into the text box, which may reset the selection to the beginning of the text.

So this method should handles pasting text, or backspacing over the first character (which is still annoying because it immediately capitalized the next character, which is most likely not what the user wanted).

Here's how it works:

```
private bool codeIsChangingText = false;
private int selectionStart;

private void txtStart_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (codeIsChangingText)
    {
        codeIsChangingText = false;
        txtStart.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
    }
    else if (char.IsLower(txtStart.Text.FirstOrDefault()))
    {
        codeIsChangingText = true;
        selectionStart = txtStart.SelectionStart;
        txtStart.Text = char.ToUpper(txtStart.Text.First()) + txtStart.Text.Substring(1);
    }
}
```